# Removing unused references and binaries VS2013, .Net

Tags: asp.net, reference, visual-studio-2013

This question has been asked many times but I am still not able to remove all unused references.  The "bin" folder of my app is getting bigger and bigger due to adding/removing references indiscriminately over the years.  I want to clean up the bin folder to have only what the app need.  I tried using "Remove unused references" but it appears there are many DLLs that are not statically linked and are loaded at run time when certain functionalities are used.  Is there a good way to clean up the project and the bin folder?

Comment: How about just Project->Clean Solution, or just deleting all files by hand then rebuilding?

Comment: Clean Solution has issues.  It does not remove files from the bin folder after I remove references and run "Clean Solution". But for some reasons, it always remove RestSharp.dll despite the fact this dll is statically referenced.

Comment: Delete them all by hand. It sounds like some files got put there manually. Save a copy of the folder first.